# Асинхронный цикл while True

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telebot, асинхронность

Каждый день бот в 20:00 должен проводить итерацию базы данных пользователей с платной подпиской и удалять тех у кого подписка истекла. Всё вроде бы сделал, но наткнулся на такую проблему: чтобы модуль `shedule` ( модуль отвечающий за выполнение функции в определённое время ) работал, должен быть активен цикл:

```
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    sleep(1)
```

так вот данный цикл блокирует все остальные команды. Позже я попытался переписать цикл асинхронным способом:

```
async def schedule_run():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(schedule_run())
```

но так как, весь бот написан синхронно, это не помогло и цикл всё равно блокирует остальной функционал бота. Переписать бота под асинхронную модель мягко говоря будет трудно, так как он состоит из 2100 строк кода. Вообщем мне нужно узнать, как сделать так, чтобы цикл выполнялся параллельно от всех остальных функций в боте.

Вот данный отрезок кода:

```
def db_check_pro_user(user_id):
    row, user_id, sub_type, date_buy, date_stop = db_get_pro_user(user_id)
    today = datetime.date.today()
    if today == date_stop:
        if sub_type == 1:
            bot.send_message(user_id, text="Тут текст", parse_mode="Markdown")
        elif sub_type == 2:
            bot.send_message(user_id, text="Тут текст", parse_mode="Markdown")

        db_del_pro_user(user_id)

def check_start():
    today = datetime.date.today()
    users = db_get_pro_users()

    for user in users:
        user_id = user[0]
        db_check_pro_user(user_id)

schedule.every().day.at("20:00").do(check_start)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    sleep(1)
```

Бот написан на библиотеке telebot.

Comment: простите. не правильно прочитал. если бот синхронный, то асинхронная функция никак не поможет.

Comment: а у вас есть какой то основной цикл самого бота?

Comment: Основного цикла нет

Comment: единственный костыль который могу предложить, в наиболее часто используемой функции, или функции которая у вас вызывается с определенной периодичностью, вставить функцию проверки времени, если время >20:00 и <20:10 то запустить проверку пользователей. и допустим в переменную записать дату, что бы перед проверкой времени смотреть, была ли уже проверка сегодня

Comment: Посмотрел документацию на telebot. Так как его цикл ожидания находится внутри функции infinity_polling решил посмотреть ее исходники. Но при ее поисках в исходниках нашел готовый пример ее использования совместно с shedule https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/8d49d220741c12e542719c36fa2d33ad10722820/examples/timer_bot.py

Comment: Если у вас сам бот синхронный, а вы пытаетесь написать асинхронную функцию, то мне кажется что-то здесь уже не так :D Если есть возможность то вам проще будет переписать бота на асинхронщину, но допустим этот вариант не подходит, тогда попробуйте покапать в сторону celery и прикрутить периодические таски.

Comment: mike, большое спасибо, помогло. Добавьте ответ, отмечу как решение.

Comment: у меня такая же проблема, нашли решение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение проблемы - использование модуля `threading`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    threading.Thread(target=bot.infinity_polling, name='bot_infinity_polling', daemon=True).start()

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

> Позже я попытался переписать цикл асинхронным способом

В этом случае вместо `sleep()` нужно использовать `await asyncio.sleep()`.